# Child Event listener for a Firestore document and Multiple users write to a document at once?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to implement a ChildEventListener for a Firestore document (i.e. when fields are added/ removed to the document, a listener must be triggered that only gets the snapshot of the added/deleted field). Preferably, it must have an OnChildAdded, OnChildChanged and OnChildDeleted functionality, similar to the Firebase Realtime DB.

Also, is there any way for multiple users to manipulate a single Firestore document all at once without conflict?? (eg. user 1, 2 and 3 add their names to the same document at the same time). Could you provide the implementation for this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore the fields of a Document are not considered "children" of the document like they are when dealing with Realtime Database paths, so there's no way to do exactly what you want.

You can listen to realtime changes on a document though, and implement the diffing yourself to find out which fields changed:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        // ... calculate which fields changed ...
    }

});
```

Comment: I am aware of that. I wanted to know of any easier way to implement a child listener. Also, is there any way by which multiple individuals can write data on a document at the same time? Won't there be conflicts?

Comment: No, there's no way to implement a child event listener on fields of a document in the Android SDK>

Comment: As for conflicts, Firestore uses a "last write wins" model.  If you want to ensure data integrity, you can use transactions.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it in FireStore, you'll need to use ADDED, MODIFIED, REMOVED enums.

```
 //Listener
        update_listener = mDatabase.collection("Announcements").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                //If something went wrong
                if (e != null)
                    Log.w(TAG, "ERROR : ", e);

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    //Instead of simply using the entire query snapshot
                    //See the actual changes to query results between query snapshots (added, removed, and modified)
                    for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (doc.getType()) {

                            case ADDED:

                                if (!isFirstListLoaded){
                                    //Call the model to populate it with document
                                    AnnouncementModel annonPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(AnnouncementModel.class)
                                            .withId(doc.getDocument().getId());
                                    //This will be called only if user added some new post
                                    announcementList.add(0, annonPost);
                                    announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
                                    //Notify the adapter to update all position
                                    announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, announcementList.size());

                                    Log.d(TAG,"THIS SHOULD BE CALLED");

                                   /* //Just call this method once
                                    if (noContent.isShown()){
                                        //This will be called only if user added some new post
                                        announcementList.add(annonPost);
                                        announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        noContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    }*/
                                }

                                break;

                            case MODIFIED:
                                break;

                            case REMOVED:
                                //Get the document ID of post in FireStore
                                //Perform a loop and scan the list of announcement to target the correct index
                                for (int i = 0; i < announcementList.size(); i++) {
                                    //Check if the deleted document ID is equal or exist in the list of announcement
                                    if (doc.getDocument().getId().equals(announcementList.get(i).AnnouncementsID)) {
                                        //If yes then delete that object in list by targeting its index
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Removed Post: " + announcementList.get(i).getTitle());
                                        announcementList.remove(i);
                                        //Notify the adapter that some item gets remove
                                        announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                                        //Notify the adapter to update all position
                                        announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(i, announcementList.size());
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    isFirstListLoaded = false;
                }

            }
        });
```